# npm module 'bcrypt' is not installing in windows 10 and throwing error in sails

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, npm-install, bcrypt

I have a sails project which is using 'bcrypt' module and when i am trying to install it using command -

```
npm install --save bcrypt
```

but it gives me following error !!!. Also i am using npm version @3.6.0 and node version @5.6.0.Am not able to resolve this error shown below :

```
 > bcrypt@0.8.5 install C:\Users\vikas\Documents\batua-web\node_modules\bcrypt  
 > node-gyp rebuild  
 > C:\Users\vikas\Documents\batua-web\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.  
 > C:\Users\vikas\Documents\batua-web\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  
> gyp ERR! build error  
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1  
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)  
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)  
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)  
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)  
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586  
> gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-     gyp.js" "rebuild"  
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\vikas\Documents\batua-web\node_modules\bcrypt  
> gyp ERR! node -v v5.6.0  
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1  
> gyp ERR! not ok  
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586  
> npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "bcrypt"  
> npm ERR! node v5.6.0  
> npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0  
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
> npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`  
> npm ERR! Exit status 1  
> npm ERR!  
> npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.  
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.  
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,  
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.  
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
> npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild  
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:  
> npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt  
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:  
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt  
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.  
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:  
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\vikas\Documents\batua-web\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Most likely you don't have a proper build environment installed. Also, in the future you should *paste* the error text in your question instead of linking to a *picture* which is not *searchable*. Also if the picture link ever breaks, future visitors won't know what the error was.

Comment: Thanks @mscdex next time i'll take care of these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the logs I see that you are using windows operating system.

[Here on this github page of node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation), it says you need to have the following

- On Windows:

  - Python ([`v2.7.10`][python-v2.7.10] recommended, `v3.x.x` is ***not*** supported)

    - Make sure that you have a PYTHON environment variable, and it is set to drive:\path\to\python.exe not to a folder
  - Windows XP/Vista/7:

    - Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2013 ([Express][msvc2013] version works well)
    - If the install fails, try uninstalling any C++ 2010 x64&x86 Redistributable that you have installed first
    - If you get errors that the 64-bit compilers are not installed you may also need the [compiler update for the Windows SDK 7.1]
  - Windows 7/8:

    - Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2013 for Windows Desktop ([Express][msvc2013] version works well)
  - Windows 10:

    - Install the latest version of npm (3.3.6 at the time of writing)
    - Install Python 2.7 from https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/ and make sure its on the System Path
    - Install Visual Studio Community 2015 Edition. (Custom Install, Select Visual C++ during the installation)
    - Set the environment variable GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
    - Run the command prompt as Administrator
    - $ npm install (--msvs_version=2015) <-- Shouldn't be needed if you have set GYP_MSVS_VERSION env
    - If the above steps have not worked or you are unsure please visit http://www.serverpals.com/blog/building-using-node-gyp-with-visual-studio-express-2015-on-windows-10-pro-x64 for a full walkthrough
  - All Windows Versions

    - For 64-bit builds of node and native modules you will ***also*** need the [Windows 7 64-bit SDK][win7sdk]
    - You may need to run one of the following commands if your build complains about WindowsSDKDir not being set, and you are sure you have already installed the SDK:

For others operating system you can visit the [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) to see their dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I tried another way to fix this issue on Window 10. I hope it can help you.
1st step: run Powershell with Administrator role (Click right mouse on Powershell and choose "Run As Administrator")
2nd step: install **native addon build tool** and **Windows-Build-Tools**

> ```
>  npm install -g node-gyp
>  npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
> ```

3rd step: change directory to current project
4th step: install bcrypt

> ```
>  npm install bcrypt
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Install python in your windows machine this will definitely solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

First run command to install python bcoz bcrypt is an addon which need to be compiled

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python2.7
```

or

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

then run

```
npm install bcrypt
```